# can i use GCM (google cloud messaging) as sms gateway

Tags: android, eclipse, rest, google-cloud-messaging, sms-gateway

Actually I am developing an Android app for women security, its an emergency app which will send out panic messages to emergency contacts at the double click of power button of your phone, so at this double click event, only a request needs to be send to the server and the server will then send out messages to dedicated persons emergency contacts for this I need a free sms gateway or a rest api.

I only need to send messages.

Is GCM suitable?If not please suggest free gateways/api

Comment: Why can't you send message from user phone itself?

Comment: i dont want to send it from user phone because in case the users account balance will be null, the functionality will fail, and the sole purpose of emergency app will go in vain, so looking for internet messaging option

Comment: Do you think internet will be available all the time?

Comment: ya most of the time, now a days that everybody uses smartphones, data connection/wifi is part of it..and more over, il b using both ways, if net connection is not there, send mesg as regular msg else over the net..

Comment: Ok,but sms gateway are not free! its better to reserve some balance in user mobile itself.

Comment: so does that mean there's nothing more to it :( i m playing around with GCM, but not sure if it will do the needful..any insights appreciated!

Comment: GCM can be used to intimate users with internet. if not only way is to through sms may be you should recommend your users to use a postpaid  plan.

Comment: GCM isn't a SMS gateway, it won't work like SMS that the person you wanna send Message without install your App. I used Amazon SNS for this purpose that only needs the user numbers and their acceptance, and AWS offer a free-tier of SMS which equals cost free to me.

Answer (score 4):

SMS and GCM are not the same thing at all. SMS uses carrier routing, GCM uses IP (WiFi or mobile data) routing.

GCM can send messages as long as the user is connected to the internet. You can use third-party gateways (like Twilio mentioned in another answer) but there is generally a cost or other constraints.

You can also use `SmsManager` on the owner's device to send messages, but some apps may prevent this on KitKat devices (or later) since it has to route SMS through the "default" SMS app.

So, your user will need to test this. Since it is an emergency app, I'm pretty sure you don't want to worry about WiFi connection.

Also, take a look at superdupersms.com - it supports this kind of functionality.

Comment: Any app with the `SEND_SMS` permission can still send messages with `SmsManager` in KitKat and above. The primary restriction is that only the default app has standard write access to the Provider. However, any non-default app sending messages will have them automatically written to the Provider by the system.

Comment: Out of a few hundred thousand installs using that method, I've seen it not always work. Apparently, not all phones implement it properly or intentionally ignore that part of the specification. That's why I wrote what I did. Is your experience that it is fully reliable?

Comment: Gotcha. I misread your post as saying "it will not work on KitKat". Apologies. Personally, I've not come across a situation where it didn't work, but obviously specific implementations can alter that behavior. Good to know. Thanks!

Answer (score -6):

This is exactly what GCM was made for. Follow the instructions from Google and you'll be good to go.

https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html

if you only want to send an sms, why don't you just send an sms

smsManager.sendTextMessage("phoneNo", null, "SMS text", null, null);

Comment: i dont want to send it from user phone because in case the users account balance will be null, the functionality will fail, and the sole purpose of emergency app will go in vain, so looking for internet messaging option